# How to use gradio dataframe as output for an interface

Tags: python, huggingface, gradio

So I have a scraper that collects data from different sources and them returns the result as a dataframe. I currently want to create a Gradio interface that given a user input would returns the resulting dataframe as output.

`gr.Interface(fn=scraper_obj.scrape, inputs='text', outputs=gr.Dataframe(headers=['title', 'author', 'text']), allow_flagging='never').launch()`

As you can see in the above code, the interface would call the scrape function on the user input which would return a dataframe that has three columns (title, author and text) but when I try this code, it returns this output.

[image]